# How to prove that the numerator is divided by 101 $1+\frac{1}{2}+\ldots+\frac{1}{100}$

Tags: number-theory

> How to prove that: $1+\frac{1}{2}+\ldots+\frac{1}{100} = \frac{p}{q},    
>  \gcd(p,q) = 1 \Rightarrow p \vdots 101$

I tried to allocate a numerator, but nothing happened, I tried to calculate the amount manually, but this also did not lead to success, I will be happy with any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $1\leq n\leq 100$ let $1\leq r(n)\leq 100$ where  $\frac {100!}{n}\equiv r(n)\pmod {101}.$

We have $1\leq n<n'\leq 100\implies r(n)\ne r(n').$ So $\{r(n):1\leq n\leq 100\}=\{m:1\leq m\leq 100\}.$  We have  $$\sum_{n=1}^{100} \frac {1}{n}= \frac { \sum_{n=1}^{100}(100!/n)}{100!}\quad \bullet.$$  The numerator  in $\bullet$ is congruent modulo $101$ to $\sum_{n=1}^{100} r(n)=\sum_{m=1}^{100} m=100\cdot 101/2=50\cdot 101,$ so the numerator in $\bullet$ is a multiple of $101.$ And the denominator $100!$ in $\bullet$ is co-prime to $101.$  So $\bullet$ in lowest terms  must have a numerator divisible by $101.$

Another way is to consider this  in the field $F=\Bbb Z_{101}.$ Let $S=\sum_{n=1}^{100}1/n.$  Now $F$ does not have characteristic $2$, so in $F$ we have $S=\sum_{x\in F\backslash \{0\}}(x^{-1})=\sum_{y\in F\backslash \{0\}}(y)=0.$ The implication  is that in $\Bbb Z$ we have  $S=A/100!$ for some $A\in \Bbb Z,$ and if $101$ does not divide $A$ then in $\Bbb Z_{101}$ we would have $S\ne 0.$

Comment: +1, but I think that $$\sum_{n=1}^{100} \frac {1}{n}= \frac { \sum_{n=1}^{100}(100!/n)}{100!} \tag{1}$$ that is referenced as $(1)$ in the text is much easier to read.

Answer (score 4):

Hint. Note that $101$ is a prime number grater than $100$ and
$$1+\frac{1}{2}+\ldots+\frac{1}{100}=\left(1+\frac{1}{100}\right)+\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{99}\right)+\dots+\left(\frac{1}{50}+\frac{1}{51}\right).$$

P.S. See: [Wolstenholme's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolstenholme%27s_theorem) and [Proof of Wolstenholme's theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/325491/proof-of-wolstenholmes-theorem) . Actually the numerator $p$ is divided by $101^2$.

Comment: It's not even a clue, but a complete solution, thank you! :)

Comment: See the second link.

Comment: Hmm, I had a reasonable question, a combination of this theorem and something else can not prove the divergence of the harmonic series?

Comment: We can show that the harmonic number $H_n$ diverges $2$-adically see http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/gradnumthy/padicharmonicsum.pdf

Comment: -1 that is almost a link only answer.

Comment: @miracle173 Is it better now?

Comment: better, but not good.But the OP posted that he is "happy with any help" and accepted your answer. So there is no reason to write a good , complete answer.

Comment: @miracle173 Wow! Mine is only a hint. It was not my intention to give a full answer.

Answer (score 1):

In ganeraly:

If p is prime number and $p>2$ and
$$\frac mn=1+\frac12+\frac13+...+\frac1{p-1}$$
then $p|m$

[image]

Then $p|m$

Comment: Роман, большое спасибо за доказательство данной теоремы на русском языке, но побоюсь, что нас не поймут англоговорящие пользователи :).

Comment: Кстати говоря, не подскажите, что за книжка?

Comment: "Зарубежные математические олимпиады" под ред. Сергеева

Comment: -3: posting a photo of text, posting the text of another author without refernce, posting a Russion text with any Explanation/Translation.

Comment: I will translate it later