# Regarding a question in elementary number theory

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, divisibility, gcd-and-lcm

I am trying assignment of an Institute in which I am not a student and I am unable to think about this problem.

> **Problem** If there exist integers $a$ and $b$ such that $(a, b) = 1$ and $1+ \frac{1}{2} + \ldots + \frac{1}{p-1} = \frac{a}{b}$ then prove that $p^2 | a$ , assuming that $p\geq 3$.

Can someone please help how to approach this problem.

Comment: [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/325491/proof-of-wolstenholmes-theorem) is another duplicate

Comment: @gandalf61  The claim is true for prime $p>3$.  This is [Wolstenholme's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolstenholme%27s_theorem)

Comment: @lulu Yes, but the OP actually wrote $p \ge 3$. XWLPDK seems to have a history of mistyping questions and perhaps needs to take more care.

Comment: @gandalf61  Good point.