# Why Wolstenholme's theorem is not true for p=2, 3

Tags: proof-explanation, analytic-number-theory

Theorem 5.25 in Apostol's Analytic Number Theory book (Wolstenholme's theorem) states that the following holds for any prime $p \ge 5$ : $$\sum_{k=1}^{p-1} \dfrac{(p-1)!}{k} = 0 \mod p^2.$$ I read and read the proof but I never found somewhere when $p=2, 3$ are invalid. That is, in the process of proof there is nowhere when the proof fails for $p=2, 3$. However, the statement does not hold for $p=2, 3$ and holds for $p=5$. Perhaps in order for $S_1$ to appear in $g(x)$, $p=2$ has been put aside, but $S_{p-2}=S_1$ for $p=3$ still is valid. So how is the proof valid for $p=2,3$ as well but the Wolstenholme's identity is not valid for $p=2,3$?

[image]

Comment: Just take $p=2$ or $p=3$ and go through the proof line by line until it breaks down.   In either case the sums (or binomial symbols, or factorials) will all be very simple.  In the [Wkipedia proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolstenholme%27s_theorem#A_proof_of_the_theorem) of an equivalent version, at some point there is an explicit division by $3$, for instance.  Without seeing the proof you have in mind, there's not a lot more to say.

Comment: In [this proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/325491/proof-of-wolstenholmes-theorem) the problem comes from the sum of squares formula, which has a $6$ in the denominator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is just before the end of the proof, where an equation is taken modulo $p^3$. If $p \ge 5$, then this will cancel all terms except $-S_{n-1}p$, but if $p=3$, then $p^{p-1} = 9$ is not divisible by $p^3 = 27$ and will not be cancelled either.

In that case, you get $3S_1 \equiv 3^2 = 9$ mod 27, so $S_1 \equiv 3$ mod 9, which is confirmed by the actual sum being $S_1 = 3$.